# /usr/bin/codesign from Mac 10.9

Tags: macos, mac, code-signing

The /usr/bin/codesign file on our server was removed.  It is running version OS version 10.9.   Does anyone know where I can download the codesign file for OSX 10.9?  Or can anyone pull it off their computers for me?

Comment: Do you have Xcode 5.x with the command line tools installed ?? - I have the codesign tool with my Mavericks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From OS X 10.9.1: [/usr/bin/codesign](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ugb2iz06ijvbys3/codesign)

Alternatively, grab it from your Recovery HD:

```
diskutil mount Recovery\ HD
hdiutil mount /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.dmg
sudo cp /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/usr/bin/codesign /usr/bin/codesign
```

<sup>I recommend you do a permissions repair after copying.</sup>

Comment: We might need a canonical, where can I get file X that I just removed from my Mac....

Comment: @bmike I've written a canonical Q&A for that (still think the question could be improved a bit maybe): http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/ive-deleted-x-system-file-from-my-mac-how-can-i-recover-it

Comment: I like how the canonical question is working out. Hit me up in [chat] this weekend. It might be nice to pick another sort of canonical question or two to try asking / answering. Perhaps a fun one like Clash of Clans / Game Center and another more serious one.